# Increase the amount of preloaded video on YouTube

Tags: youtube

My connection does not always have a consistent speed. Sometimes I can load a minute of a YouTube video in 10 seconds, while other times there is no loading and I get stuck seeing the spinning loading circle. Currently YouTube never loads more than a minute or two in advance.

Is there a way that I can increase the amount of content YouTube pre-loads, perhaps 5 or 10 minutes of video?

Comment: Is YouTube Red available in your region? You can download videos offline with it.

Comment: @jonsca Why the Firefox tag doesn't fit, if the user is looking for a solution for Firefox?

Comment: @arieljannai That's something the user should specify in the body of the question rather than the tags.  `Firefox` would be useful if there were a bug or particular quirk of Firefox that made it the subject of the question rather than just a peripherally related component of it.

Comment: So in that case there should've been a mention in the post, but not a `Firefox` tag, correct?

Comment: @arieljannai Correct.  It's a bit nuanced, but if you look at some of the other questions tagged with Firefox, it'll become more evident as to how it's been used.  In this case, had the pre-loading been different on Firefox than Chrome, for example, that would have been relevant to the actual question that was being asked.

Answer (score 1):

Try the SmartVideo [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smartvideo-for-youtube/lnkdbjbjpnpjeciipoaflmpcddinpjjp?hl=en) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smartvideo-for-youtube-mytube/) extension.

Comment: I use Firefox, sorry.

Comment: firefox has the same extension -
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/smartvideo-for-youtube-mytube/